# Error: certificate, asymmetric key, or private key file is not valid or does not exist; or you do not have permissions for it. Generating this in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, certificate, virtual-machine, ssms, private-key

We're currently working on POC of restoring DB in SQL Managed Instance & on SQL Server On VM.

1. We've created Master Key, Certificate & restored DB in Managed Instance.
2. Now trying to do the same in SQL Server on VM but SSMS is throwing error

> The certificate, asymmetric key, or private key file is not valid or does not exist; or you do not have permissions for it.

Please let me know what to do.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQJnI.png)

Please let me know what to do.

Comment: Post your SQL as code, then you don't need the image.

Comment: Was the backup actually encrypted using that certificate? What is the result of `select * from master.sys.certficates`? Please do not post images of code or data, please paste in as text.

Comment: Your master keys have to much exactly on both environments: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-master-key-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Did you copy the .cert and .pvk files into the VM's file system? SQL Server won't be able to read them from `C:\Users\fcpadmin\Downloads` on your local computer.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/238704)